# Simple modules for direct sum of simple Lie algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, modules, tensor-products

I think that the following statement is true, but I do not know how to prove it.

Let $\mathfrak{g}_1$ and $\mathfrak{g}_2$ be two real simple Lie algebras. If $M$ is a (infinite dimensional) complex simple $\mathfrak{g}_1\oplus\mathfrak{g}_2$-module, then $M\cong M_1\otimes M_2$ where $M_1$ and $M_2$ are simple modules of $\mathfrak{g}_1$ and $\mathfrak{g_2}$ respectively.

This ought to be a well known result if it is true. As is known to all, it is true for finite groups and compact groups.

Comment: I assume you want $M$ to be a module for $\mathfrak{g}_1 \oplus \mathfrak{g}_2$?

Comment: @user44191 Yes, it is what I mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is true more generally for any two finite-dimensional Lie algebras over a field. Recall that a $\frak{g}$-module is the same as a module over $U (\frak{g})$, the universal enveloping algebra of $\frak{g}$, which is an *associative* algebra. Moreover, $U ({\frak{g}_1\oplus\frak{g}_2})\simeq U({\frak{g}_1})\otimes U ({\frak{g}_2})$, so this question reduces to showing that a simple module $M$ over the tensor product $A_1\otimes A_2$ decomposes as $M_1\otimes M_2$, where $M_i$ is a simple module over a universal enveloping algebra $A_i$. If my memory serves, there is proof along these lines in Dixmier, "Universal enveloping algebras". Another standard reference is McConnell and Robson, "Noncommutative Noetherian rings".

Comment: That is great! Thank you so much!